# Making a function to manipulate an integer

Tags: python, function

I want to make a function to transform an integer.

For example:

```
d = "1209834"
```

I want to , in one function, turn it into an integer, then turn it into a binary, then strip off the `0b` prefix. So I'd just get `100100111010111101010` as a result when the function is applied.

Comment: I am concerned with making a function to apply various transformations under the umbrella of one function.

Comment: Okay, cool. You've told us what you want to do. What's your question? Please read [ask], and remember that we're not here to write code for you.

Answer (score 4):

Can use built-in [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) and [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

```
>>> bin(int(d))[2:]
'100100111010111101010'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in one line:

```
d = "1209834"
int_d = int(d)
binary_d = "{0:b}".format(int_d) # binary of d as a string
```

Comment: And in Python 3.6+ you can do the same thing with an f-string: `binary_d = f'{int_d:b}'` or `binary_d = f'{int(d):b}'`

Comment: @martineau, more than one line to make it clearer to understand for the OP, who seems to be a beginner. Thanks.